# How can I throw the error when STOP condition is raised ( Progress openEdge )

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Something like:

DO ON STOP UNDO, THROW:

code
FINALLY:
code
END FINALLY.

END.

Comment: Please indicate the OpenEdge release - as handling of stop conditions has changed in OpenEdge 12 and optionally the later OpenEdge 11.7 service packs.

Comment: release: OpenEdge 12.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In OpenEdge 12 you can CATCH Stop conditions. Depending on the cause, you can CATCH:

- Progress.Lang.StopError (e.g. execute non existing procedure)
- Progress.Lang.LockConflict
- Progress.Lang.StopAfter (Block with STOP-AFTER option)
- Progress.Lang.UserInterrupt
- Progress.Lang.Stop (generic STOP condition)

Progress.Lang.StopError extends Progress.Lang.SysError and can be CATCHed with Progress.Lang.Error too

The other STOP conditions all extend Progress.Lang.Stop and could be CATCHed with that type.